# Can Someone please explain this Code to me

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

```
inputArray=[5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4]
product = -1000
f = 0


for f in range(len(inputArray)):
    try:
        if product<  inputArray[f] * inputArray[f+1]:
             product = inputArray[f] * inputArray[f+1]
             print product
    except:
        'no more'
print product
```

Result: 5,6

why doesn't it keep multiply the rest of the adjacent elements?

Comment: What result are you expecting? Alsom can you specify the expected behavior you want?

Comment: it does. it just doesnt print because they don't meet the product being less than current iteration multiplied by next iteration condition. It works because initially product is negative, which will mean the first item in the array will always print. then after that the only time product is less than the current iteration times next iteration is 2, 3 - or 2 * 3 which is 6, which currently happens when product is 5. 5 < 6, therefore, print.

Comment: @KaiQing Oh ok I understand now, so basically, the product turns into 5 in the iteration then if in the next iteration the product is not greater than 5 it will remain the same until one of the products is greater than 5, therefore, the product turns into 6

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like that as an official answer, the explanation is below:

It does multiply on every iteration. It just doesn't print and redefine product unless product is less than the value of this iteration multiplied by next iteration. so visualize it like so:

-1000 < 5 so print. now the value of product is 5.

5 > 1 * 2 so do nothing.

5 < 2 * 3 so print. the value of product is now 6.

6 > 3 * 1 so do nothing.

6 > 1 * 4 so do nothing.

So you would have printed only 5 and 6.